# Using Proxies with Python Requests (Pytrends)

Tags: python, google-trends

i'm currently learning how to use Python with API's and am having trouble with using proxies when making requests, in this case I am using Pytrends.

Here is my code

```
`pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360, timeout=(10, 25), retries=2, backoff_factor=0.1 proxies = ['https': 'https://geo.iproyal.com:redacted'])`
                    pytrends.build_payload(kw_list=[keyword], geo=location)
                    data = pytrends.interest_over_time()
                    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
                    uk_data = int(df.iloc[-1][keyword])
```

Getting This Error

```
line 84, in GetGoogleCookie
    proxy = {'https': self.proxies[self.proxy_index]}
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 0
```

Thanks.

Tried to use residential proxies from IP Royal however have received the error displayed above, any ideas?